# How to query for no records Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm new to Elasticsearch, using version 7.1.2. I am setting up an index which contains time-stamped records for users. I would like to find out how to search for all users who are not active (i.e. have no records) over a period of time. I can create another index which contains a list of all users, but am not sure how to combine the two in a query and search for users with no records.

My simplified version of my records mapping looks like:

```
    PUT /records
    {
        "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "user_id" : {"type": "text"},
            "user_name" : {"type": "keyword"},
            "date" : {"type": "date"}
             }
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

as far as I have understood, you want to find the records that don't have value (date) set to a field (date). If I am right, this [`exists`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-query.html) query can help you.

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": {
        "exists": {
          "field": "date"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, it's more complicated in that I want to find if records exist for a combination of userid and date range for all users.  So I think what I can do is set up an index that contains all userids, then I can create a script that goes through each userid and queries whether any log records exist for that userid and date range.  I think that should do it.  Just need to figure out the specifics now.  Thank you.

Comment: First of all, you don't need another index to set up for all ids. If you are using python client for scripts, you can use `helpers.scan` for retrieving all userids. While retrieving all userids, consider storing "_id"  of each record. Then with combination of above mentioned query and `GET /_search { "query": { "ids" : { "values" : ["1", "4", "100"] } }}` you can achieve that, I believe.

Comment: That's really helpful - thank you.  I'm still not clear however on how I could access such a script from Kibana so that I could use the results in a dashboard.  Thanks.